# Algorithm to scan Lyapunov candidate functions

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

Let's say you are trying to establish the stability of an equilibrium point in a nonlinear system, but you are having trouble coming up with an appropriate Lyapunov function. (Or, you're lazy and don't want to do the work yourself.)

Are there any functions/algorithms (e.g. in Mathematica, Sage, or Python) for finding Lyapunov functions for any given nonlinear system? I can't seem to find any with a quick Google search, but it seems like it would be relatively simple to implement something that is very likely (maybe not 100% guaranteed) to find a Lyapunov function if one exists. Especially if the number of variables in the system is relatively small.

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

- Iterate over a list of positive definite functions $V(x)$ (e.g. quadratic forms and other polynomials).
- For each candidate function, determine if $\dot{V}$ is negative semidefinite or negative definite.
- Stop when you find a negative definite $\dot{V}$ or give up after a user-defined number of iterations

Would this work, or is this a more complicated problem than I'm making it out to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For nonlinear systems the Sum of Square polynomial Lyapunov function can be constructed algorithmically. See [On the Construction of Lyapunov Functions using
the Sum of Squares Decomposition](http://www.eng.ox.ac.uk/~labap/CDC02_1.pdf). Basically the sos approximation constraint the polynomial optimization of finding a Lyapunov function to be a semidefinite program, which is generally considered solvable (for low dimension cases). For implementation in Matlab, see [SOSTOOLS](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/sostools/), which is a parser for constructing polynomial optimization problems. There are recent work in using so-called DSOS and SDSOS relaxation that constraints the problem further to more solvable linear programming or second-order cone programming. However, all of the above can not guarantee to find a Lyapunov function, because, first, for a global asymptotically stable ode system with polynomial vector fields, it does not necessarily have a polynomial Lyapunov function; second, for such a system that has a polynomial Lyapunov function, it does not necessarily has a Lyapunov function that can be found by SOS programming, see Pable Parrilo's work.